# Cada siete horas mostrar un aviso que dure activo una hora en una pagina web

Tags: html, blogger, cshtml

La idea es así:
A las 6.00 am Argentina quiero que se muestre un aviso (sea imagen) que permanezca activo durante una hora, es decir, que pueda estar visible y que al cumplir los 60min se oculte, osea, a las 7.00 am se oculta. Que esta acción se repita cada 7 horas. Por lo tanto quiero que permanezca oculto durante 7 horas y vuelva a repetir la acción. A las 14.00hs aparece y a las 15.00hs se oculta. Pasan las 7 horas. Vuelve a aparecer a las 22.00hs y a las 23.00hs se oculta. Pasan las 7 horas y aparece otra vez a las 6.00 am.

EDIT: Tengo este código que @ordago - QUÉDATE EN CASA  me dejó como ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

```js
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
var horarios1 = [6 + offset, 14 + offset, 22 + offset];
var elemento1 = document.getElementById("panel1");
var horarios2 = [0 + offset];
var elemento2 = document.getElementById("panel2");
setInterval(function() {
 var hora = new Date().getHours();
 if (horarios1.includes((hora + offset) % 24)) {
   elemento1.style.display = 'block';
 } else {
   elemento1.style.display = 'none';
 }
 if (horarios2.includes((hora + offset) % 24)) {
   elemento2.style.display = 'block';
 } else {
   elemento2.style.display = 'none';
 }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="panel1" style="display: none;">PANEL 6, 14, 22</div>
<div id="panel2" style="display: none;">PANEL 0</div>
```

Tiene 2 juegos de horarios ya que se trata de dos alertas, pero como puedo hacer que se pueda ver en distintos países al mismo tiempo? Hasta ahora solo se reproduce a la misma hora que figura en el array. Es decir, a mi me sale a las 6am Argentina, en otros paises sale a las 6am pero de ellos. Lo que busco es que cuando me salga a mi, también salga en los otros países al mismo tiempo. Por ejemplo: Si en mi pais son las 6am se muestra el anuncion y al mismo tiempo se muestra en los angeles a pesar de que halla son las 2am

Comment: has probado a cojer la hora actual del sistema con `momentoActual = new Date()`
y compararla con las 6am, 14am y 22am? si coincide, muestras el mensaje, sino no haces nada... revisa este enlace: https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/549.php?manual=22